# Building a bitcoin "flip-clock" ticker

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to build a bitcoin "flip-clock" price ticker.

- I want to build a physical number flipper, with numbers from 0-9. I was thinking about LED matrix, or e-ink display, but that's not as exciting as a real flipper
- The price would get updated every 5 or 10 minutes, by checking some public API
- Everything would be controller by Raspberry Pi, Arduino or similar single board computer

I want to make as many things as possible from scratch.

- Design the 3D parts
- Print the 3D parts needed
- Wire and assemble things together
- Write the appropriate scripts

I chose this project, because it would be something cool to have on a desk, and would serve a purpose. Plus it involves a lot of different fields I want to play around in, but at a fairly light level:

- 3D printing
- 3D designing
- Engineering
- Programming

---

**Now here's the problem... I have no idea where to start.**

I'm good at fixing things, taking things apart and putting them back together, had quite some experience with 3D programs like 10 years ago, have some experience with programming (php, js). But I never built anything from scratch.

So, I'm not sure whether this is the right place, but I want to start a thread to continuously ask questions, and progress forward.

First things is first is probably choosing the setup?

I was thinking Raspberry Pi or Arduino? I would only need a simple computer which would be able to connect to the internet (preferably wifi) and fetch the price every once in a while.

Maybe having a Raspberry Pi would be an overkill? As I only need a simple operation. And preferably I wouldn't want to rely on SD card (maybe I am wrong, but I think they might die off after a while, since this ticker would be on 24/7)?

---

**Any thoughts, comments, suggestions are welcome!**

Also, if I am in a wrong board / site, I appreciate if you would point me to the right direction.

---

**UPDATE**

I found a good open-source split-flat project: https://www.tindie.com/products/scottbez1/split-flap-display-kit-4-characters/

Comment: Welcome to engineering.SE! I think this question is a bad fit for this page in its current state, because the question is very open and broad. Starting a thread to regularly ask questions fits better into a "classic forum" than on this Q&A site. When you have a specific question like "How do I design this clock part so that it doesn't break" (just a random example), it will fit better here and you can get good answers.

Comment: Thingiverse has a number of "perpetual calendar" flip-chip designs like this one -- https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1785261  . Perhaps you can adapt such things to your needs.

Comment: Or even closer:  https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4533886  (arduino-driven flip clock)

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.